# Symfony2 - throwing AccessDeniedHttpException don't work EDIT: Security

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, symfony-components

I would like to **remove** unwanted effect of redirecting when somewhere is thrown `AccesDeniedException`. I mean redirecting to "login" page if user is not authenticated.

I created `kernel.exception` listener

```
class ApiAccessDeniedListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $format;

    public function __construct($format = 'json')
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        // here some conditions
        if($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException){
            $exception = new AccessDeniedHttpException('You do not have the necessary permissions', $exception);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array('onKernelException', 5),
        );
    }
}
```

This listener work properly in the correct order but all time firewall redirect me to login page.
[Symfony docs say](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html) that:

> **Exception Listener**
>
> If any of the listeners throws an AuthenticationException, the
>   exception listener that was provided when adding secured areas to the
>   firewall map will jump in.
>
> The exception listener determines what happens next, based on the
>   arguments it received when it was created. It may start the
>   authentication procedure, perhaps ask the user to supply their
>   credentials again (when they have only been authenticated based on a
>   "remember-me" cookie), or transform the exception into an
>   **AccessDeniedHttpException**, which will eventually result in an
>   "HTTP/1.1 403: Access Denied" response.

I understand - If I throw `AccessDeniedHttpException` i should get instant 403 instead of redirecting, 
Am I correct?

Second - I dug symfony and [ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php) have the same trick? i think...

```
private function handleAccessDeniedException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event, AccessDeniedException $exception)
{
    $event->setException(new AccessDeniedHttpException($exception->getMessage(), $exception));
    //...
}
```

In addition symfony debugger show 2 exceptions after auth. (as it should):

```
Unable to access this page!
403 Forbidden - AccessDeniedHttpException
1 linked Exception: ... (and here AccessDeniedException)
```

First `AccessDeniedException` and second `AccessDeniedHttpException`.

How can i fix my problem? How can I throw instant 403 error?

---

### EDIT

I found where is problem. Firewall `ExceptionListener` check all previous exceptions with loop:

```
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        do {
            if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                return $this->handleAuthenticationException($event, $exception);
            } elseif ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                return $this->handleAccessDeniedException($event, $exception);
            } elseif ($exception instanceof LogoutException) {
                return $this->handleLogoutException($exception);
            }
        } while (null !== $exception = $exception->getPrevious());
    }
```

I can change my listener to:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    // here some conditions
    if($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException){
        //old version
        //$exception = new AccessDeniedHttpException('You do not have the necessary permissions', $exception);
        $exception = new AccessDeniedHttpException('You do not have the necessary permissions', $exception->getPrevious());
    }
}
```

**New question is - Could it cause any security problems?**
I think this is good way.